# Unable to Add GameObjects to defined List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm struggling with this problem for 2 days, I'm trying to add `go` GameObject into a list `changedObjects` but i don't know why `changedObjects` is `Null`.

I tried this:

```
public class UndoObject : MonoBehaviour {
    private List<GameObject> changedObjects;

    void Start () {
        changedObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    }

    public void Push(GameObject go) {
        Debug.Log(changedObjects);
        if (go != null) {
            changedObjects.Add(go);
        }
    }

    public List<GameObject> GetAll () {
        return changedObjects;
    }
}
```

Than I call `UndoObject.Push` from another class with GameObject.

But, it keep throwing error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   UndoObject.Push (UnityEngine.GameObject go) (at Assets/Standard Assets/Scripts/UndoObject.cs:15)
>   Manager.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Scripts/Manager.cs:73)

**UndoObject.cs:15** is `changedObjects.Add(go);`

Comment: are you calling start() before calling add() ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes, is that wrong?

Comment: please post that code too

Comment: @Sajeetharan The code is right here, that's the whole code i have. Are you asking for code where i called `UndoObject.Push`?

Comment: yes, where you call push and start method

Comment: No, calling start before is not bad. It is mandatory. Personalyl I would put the initialsiation code into Push itself [if (changedObjects = null) changedObjects = new List<GameObject>();] But it is a mater of pattern if you do explciitly or implicit initlisation of that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are calling the push method directly without calling start() which will initialize the array, however you can add this inside your push method to make sure array is always initialized.

```
 public void Push(GameObject go) {
        if (changedObjects == null)
        { 
           changedObjects = new List<GameObject>();
        }
        if (go != null) {
            changedObjects.Add(go);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Hm, Thanks. I figured why mine is not working. I never assigned `UndoObject` to any gameObject *facepalm*